# In ECB in Emacs how can I switch to the browser window using the keyboard?

Tags: emacs

I've looked at the documentation and can only seem to find a way to access the Emacs ECB browser window by left clicking the mouse in the browser area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using menubar — ECB -> Goto window -> ...

Or hotkeys. For example for switching to filesystem browser use function (ecb-goto-window-directories), which is bound to "C-c . g d" by default.

Answer (score 11):

Keyboard navigation:

ECB windows from bottom to top.

- Go to history: "C-c . g h"
- Go to methods: "C-c . g m"
- Go to sources: "C-c . g s"
- Go to directories: "C-c . g d"

Main buffer: "C-c . g 1"

Answer (score 3):

I have this in my .emacs

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-left>") 'ecb-goto-window-methods)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-right>") 'ecb-goto-window-edit1)
```

You can similarly use more friendly key combinations to access the ecb window you want.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the same bindings as Raja Selvaraj, but at least in my ECB version (20120612.1129) its unnecessary to add extra mappings.

By default <kbd>M-left</kbd> / <kbd>M-right</kbd> are bound to *windmove-left* / *windmove-right* functions, that allow to switch to and from ECB Browser easily.