# How do you jump window with Emacs Code Browser?

Tags: emacs

I am learning emacs for programming, and use [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net) to browse code. I found that it is not quick enough to jump between windows with (C-c . gd , C-c . gs, C-s. g1). Is there any better idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293554/in-ecb-in-emacs-how-can-i-switch-to-the-browser-window-using-the-keyboard/13529574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are packages which let you navigate between windows [with the arrow keys, etc.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWindows#toc2).